# How do you set the quality for RenderTarget2D.SaveAsJpeg()?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xna-4.0

```
public void SaveAsJpeg(Stream stream, int width, int height)
```

RenderTarget2D.SaveAsJpeg() is missing a parameter to set the Jpeg quality and the output has lots of artifacts. (increasing the size of the image does help a bit but it still looks bad)

Is that parameter hidden somewhere in XNA? How can I improve the quality of the jpeg?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no quality parameter in the XNA 4.0 API for encoding JPEG images.

As a very round-about way of doing things, you may be able to create a Silverlight `WriteableBitmap`, copy the data out of your render target and into that, and then use [`Extensions.SaveJpeg`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.extensions.savejpeg(v=vs.92).aspx) to save it with a custom quality level.

A better alternative might be to simply save a PNG image.

Answer (score 0):

I will agree with Andrew Russel that a much better alternative would be to simply save to PNG, but if you simply HAVE to save to jpg, then there is a much better way than go trhough WriteableBitmap.

What you can do is create an empty Bitmap object and transfer the texture data over so you will do a Texture2D to Bitmap convertion. Simply copy from below:

```
    public static Bitmap ToBitmap(this Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics.Texture2D rd, int Width, int Height)
    {
        var Bmp = new Bitmap(Width, Height, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);

        byte[] data = ToBytes(rd);

        var bmpData = Bmp.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, rd.Width, rd.Height), System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageLockMode.WriteOnly, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);

        System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy(data, 0, bmpData.Scan0, data.Length);

        Bmp.UnlockBits(bmpData);

        return Bmp;
    }

    public static byte[] ToBytes(this Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics.Texture2D rd)
    {
        byte[] data = new byte[4 * rd.Height * rd.Width];
        rd.GetData<byte>(data);

        SwapBytes(data);

        return data;
    }

    private static void SwapBytes(byte[] data)
    {
        System.Threading.Tasks.ParallelOptions po = new System.Threading.Tasks.ParallelOptions();
        po.MaxDegreeOfParallelism = -1;

        System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.For(0, data.Length / 4, po, t =>
        {
            int bi = t * 4;
            byte temp = data[bi];
            data[bi] = data[bi + 2];
            data[bi + 2] = temp;
        });
    }
```

Note that the above is pretty efficient, but with certain drawbacks. A similar code to the above can be used to very quickly achieve a Bitmap to Texture2D convertion, but without premultiplying alpha.